# How to use await instead of .then() in Dart

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I'm having the following lines in a Flutter app. `_devicesRef` refers to some node in a Firebase Realtime Database.

```
_devicesRef.child(deviceId).once().then((DataSnapshot data) async {
    print(data.key);
    var a = await ...
    print(a);
}
```

These lines work fine. Now I want to use `await` instead of `.then()`. But somehow, `once()` never returns.

```
var data = await _devicesRef.child(deviceId).once();
print(data.key);
var a = await ...
print (a);
```

So `print(data.key)` is never called.

What's wrong here?

Comment: are you calling await _devicesRef.child ... inside a method ?

Comment: Yes `Future<void> generateSomeId() async { ... }`

Comment: hmm, that's weird it should work, do you know if there is data ?

Comment: In 99% not. I want to create an ID and check whether that ID already exists in the database. So I create a random string and try to get this node. If it exists, I have to create a new ID. If it does not exist, then I'll add it do the DB. So it's more a check to see whether a node already exists or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be explained by the code following your snippet. Perhaps the future completion is trigger by something after your code and transforming your code with await will wait until a completion that never happens.

For instance, the following code works:

```
main() async {
  final c = Completer<String>();
  final future = c.future;
  future.then((message) => print(message));
  c.complete('hello');
}
```

but not this async/await version:

```
main() async {
  final c = Completer<String>();
  final future = c.future;
  final message = await future;
  print(message);
  c.complete('hello');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to use `await` as a replacement of `.then()` in your snippet, this is how you can accomplish it:

```
() async {
    var data = await _devicesRef.child(deviceId).once();
    print(data.key);
    var a = await ...
    print(a);
}();
```

By placing the code in the asynchronous closure `() async {}()`, we are not preventing execution of the code that comes after, in a similar fashion to using `.then()`.

Answer (score 0):

it should be encased in an async function like this to use await

```
Furtre<T> myFunction() async {
  var data = await _devicesRef.child(deviceId).once();
  return data;
}
```