# Variable declared outside of if statement not retaining assignment (Flutter/Firebase Realtime Database)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to set a variable token to the data I retrieve from Firebase Realtime database. token is assigned within a if statement and the assignment works but outside of the if statement, token becomes null. token is declared outside of the if statement so I'm a bit confused why it's not being assigned to the data from Firebase.

```
sendNotification(
    BuildContext context, String title, String message, String userID) async {
  DatabaseReference databaseReference = tokensRef.child(userID);
  DataSnapshot snapshot = await databaseReference.once();
  String token;
  if (snapshot != null) {
    databaseReference.get().then((result) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = result.value;
      if (values == null) {
        token = null;
      } else {
        token = values['deviceToken'];
        //print(token);
      }
    });
  }
  print(token);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get()` call loads data from the database, which happens asynchronously (since it may take some time). While the data is being loaded, the rest of your code continues execute so that the user can continue using the app. Then when the data is available, your `then` is executed.

This means that your `print(token)` outside of the `then` now runs before the `token = values['deviceToken']` is ever execute, so it will never print the value you want because *that value hasn't loaded yet*.

For this reason, any code that needs the data from the database needs to be inside the `then` code block, like your commented `//print(token)`.

If you want to return the data, you will need to return the `Future` that `get()` returns.

---

Alternatively you can use `async`/`await`, which make the `then` part a bit more recognizable:

```
if (snapshot != null) {
  var result = await databaseReference.get()
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = result.value;
  if (values == null) {
    token = null;
  } else {
    token = values['deviceToken'];
  }
}
print(token);
```

Behind the scenes this still does the exact same thing. The compiler just generates some of that code for you, allowing you to look at something that's a bit closer to what you're probably used to.

---

Also see:

- The Flutter documentation on [asynchronous programming: futures, async, await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await).
- [how to check whether the dataSnapshot null on Flutter Firebase (Realtime) Database plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68199592/how-to-check-whether-the-datasnapshot-null-on-flutter-firebase-realtime-databa)
- [How to use await instead of .then() in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53755005/how-to-use-await-instead-of-then-in-dart/59297504#59297504)